# Can I use mutex or key word(static) instead of volatile in C++?

Tags: c++, mutex, volatile

I know **how** volatile works in C++. However, I'm still feeling confused about **why** we need volatile. Only reason I think is we need listen whether the variable changed, as the code shows below:

```
volatile int some_int = 100;

while(some_int==100) {
    doSomething()
}
```

The programmer needs know if the word *some_int* changed, so he uses "volatile". Could I use the key word "static" instead?

Mostly, I think we should we mutex(lock) to synchronize if synchronization is necessary in multi-thread. Excuse my poor English:)

Comment: This is not a correct usage of `volatile`.

Comment: You would have to use `atomic` or `mutex` for synchronization, not `volatile`.

Comment: `volatile` is caused by devices memory mapped IO or other things out of control from the program. Normally `volatile` is useless.

Comment: *"I know how volatile works in C++."* - Actually, few people do, and I'd question that you are one of them. Please explain what you *think* it does, so it can be addressed in a potential answer.

Comment: `volatile` is primarily used to tell the *compiler* that the object's value can spontaneously change due to external influences. `static` can't accomplish this. Though, I see how they both could convey that information to the developer, for a lesser definition of "spontaneously change".

Comment: Use mutex, it is often even better than a spin lock (had you used an atomic).

Comment: @Oliv With intensive lock contention, the performance difference between mutex and spin lock is considerable.

Comment: @Oliv you may find this site of interest http://demin.ws/blog/english/2012/05/05/atomic-spinlock-mutex/

Comment: @UKMonkey Unfortunatly, this kind of toy benchmark are not applicable to real code: a code where contantions are avoided. On linux, libpthread implements mutex using first a compare and change on atomic, if it succeed, (which is what happen most of the time), the mutex is locked, otherwise it perform a systemcall that will reschedule the current thread. Here in this "wrong" benchmark, two threads are continuously accessing the same location, leading to an heavily contented execution => mutex lock will often perform a syscall and reschedule the thread. The advantage of a mutex is that if there

Comment: @UKMonkey ... is a contention, the rescheduling will increase the probability that the thread holding the lock execute its critical region and the waiting thread will only restart when the lock will be released.

Comment: @Oliv There is no requirement for std::mutex to spin for a while before giving up and waiting.  You'll find that both pthread and critical sections are able to do so; but clearly in that test the mutex didn't.  The test highlights that there is some level of contention where spinning is faster than a mutex - what that level is will clearly depend on the system; but if working on a large matrix where contention can't be completely avoided then it's an optimisation that can pay off.  In addition you state "better" - but that depends if you care about burning CPU cycles or not.

Comment: @UKMonkey so at least we agree in this code there is just always contention. Not the level of contention one would have if one were performing a block matrix multiplication. Realy it would surprise me if an implementation of mutex did not have a fast path for non-contended case, but it is true that there is no requirement on the standard for that.

Answer (score 5):

> The programmer needs know if the word some_int changed, so he uses "volatile". Could I use the key word "static" instead

`volatile` was used in C++98 in concurrent programming because C++ did not support multi-threading as language at that time and side effects of `volatile` helped to avoid some race conditions, though there were no guarantees it would/should work. Since C++11 there are tools to work with concurrent programming properly - [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), so you should stop using `volatile` for wrong purpose. Making variable `static` is completely unrelated and would not affect existence of side effects directly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP already knows that locks are the synchronization choice to use. The question is why should the `volatile` keyword remain in C++ and under what conditions should it be used.

Comment: @RichardChambers I am afraid you misinterpret question, OP thinks he knows why `volatile` is there and he is wrong, so he does not really ask about `volatile` but how to synchronize properly. At least that how I understood the question and from my understanding I do provide the answer.

Comment: @Slava: Richard is correct. I believe it is you who misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4):

> The volatile keyword is intended to prevent the compiler from applying
>   any optimizations on objects that can change in ways that cannot be
>   determined by the compiler. Objects declared as volatile are omitted
>   from optimization because their values can be changed by code outside
>   the scope of current code at any time.
>   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-volatile-qualifier-in-c/

As a long time embedded systems programmer, my perspective is that the volatile qualifier is a 'command' from me to the compiler.  On an address-by-address basis, I "order" the compiler to always perform every access I code.  The compiler accomplishes this by preventing certain code optimizations.

> why we need volatile

In memory-mapped i/o (as opposed to port i/o), my code dealt with feedback from hardware devices, indicating, for example, "transfer complete", or "buffer full", or "los" (loss-of-signal).  Each has their own urgency.

High urgency would often notify the software with an interrupt (and almost never a 'polling', as in your example). The hardware design often provides some buffering support, giving the software more time to respond to the interrupt.  In an interrupt handler, the compiler must not optimize away any hardware reads or writes.  Volatile use required.

Lower urgency is often handled by periodic status checks (again, never by polling).  Historically the telecom "los" is checked once per second.  This enables the software to report the system alarm within the required 2.5 +/- 0.5 seconds (after the los started).

The los-bit check must never be skipped. The keyword volatile commands the compiler to not remove the code doing the checking, no matter how recently the software looked at the bits.   Volatile use required.

In this context, a semaphore or atomic will not work ... the hardware I have worked on does not know those concepts.  Volatile required.

---

> Could I use the key word "static" instead?

No.

---

This is a wasteful poll:

```
volatile int some_int = 100;

while(some_int==100) {
    doSomething()
}
```

Never do this.

---

This is a (much simplified) status update:

```
// status update thread 
do
{
    waitFor_startOfSecond();  // os provided call

    // status check
    if (los(bit))   // test the los bit in hw (1 of 10000)
    {
       losActions()
    }

    // ... other stuff, including other status bits

    // Note: expect less than 1 second elapsed since start of loop
    // On at least one system, this alarm processing effort 
    // completed in < 1/3 second  (even ~10,000 alarms)

} while(1); // typically, embedded threads do not halt
```

Comment: One system I worked on had ~10,000 error bits and associated alarms.  Yes, that status update check code was worked on to be efficient.

Comment: Could you add additional material about synchronization and not using volatile within a multithreading application with the expectation that is a reliable way for inter-thread communication?

Comment: @RichardChambers - I think the idea of using volatile for such things is not a good fit for this post.  But I think it is a reasonable question.  However, I'm not sure 'unreasonable' answers would be received well.  and I'm  not confident that I can remember enough details to explain.  Did you ever use PDP11s with RSX11?

Comment: Never used PDP11. Did use VAX and Gould Firebreather and Perkin-Elmer 32 bit mini-computers back in the early 1980s. With FORTRAN.

Answer (score 1):

> Mostly, I think we should we mutex(lock) to synchronize if synchronization is necessary in multi-thread.

You're right.

And, if you have mutexes, you don't need `volatile` (as the load guarantees are already there).

> The programmer needs know if the word some_int changed, so he uses "volatile".

That's true, or at least it would be if `some_int` were instead some value provided by a piece of hardware, or some other part of the computer, not under your program's control. Your program can't tell when such a value has been changed externally.

Like:

```
volatile int* ptr_to_some_int = 0x0123456; // hardcoded address to somewhere magical!

printf("%d", *ptr_to_some_int); // okay, we'll get some value

// But the value of *ptr_to_some_int may have changed here...

printf("%d", *ptr_to_some_int); // ... so here it must be assuredly reloaded
```

> I'm still feeling confused about why we need volatile.

If the above is not the case, then you don't.

> Could I use the key word "static" instead?

No, `static` is completely unrelated.

Comment: "were instead some value provided by a piece of hardware" ... such as another core updating shared memory?

Comment: "if you have mutexes, you don't need volatile" - I disagree, and consider this is a more complex choice.  In certain telecom embedded systems, the alarm-bit-check is typically scheduled, and all bits are checked by the single thread (one system had >10K bits).  There is no contention when you schedule, so mutex adds no value.  And unrelated threads don't read these these bits, so mutex adds no value.  The volatile is still useful, however, to handle some hw complexities ... the compiler should never 'remove' a bit read/write during these ops.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: _"such as another core updating shared memory?"_ Yes, exactly. _"The volatile is still useful, however, to handle some hw complexities"_ Yes, and 2/3rds of my answer talks about just that. The _"if you have mutexes, you don't need volatile"_ may be read as if it continues _"for thread-safety"_, as the quote it relates to is talking specifically about synchronisation.